# how to find a specific process by pid in htop

Tags: htop

I try find a specific process by pid, in htop, the search function toggled by F3, seems can't do this.

I type in 512, instead of 512 process, the process with pid 710 is highlighted.

Comment: search is for the command column, you can sort by pid but not search

Comment: You simply type the pid without selecting search and it finds it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Found this in [`htop` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/htop):

> Numbers PID search: type in process ID and the selection highlight
>   will be moved to it.

So you basically just type in the process PID in the main view without entering search and it will select the process of the entered PID.

Comment: Well, that's not intuitive, but it's well described in the help (press `F1`).